# Countdown timer replacing div element

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to learn some java script doing a work interview evaluation project. The issue is that I have a timer, when the timer reaches zero it should replace the div containing it with another div containing text and an image. I searched but could not find an example like this.
Here is the code for the timer, I think I am supposed to put something after the clearTimeout, but everything I tried did not work:

```
function cdtd() {
var kickoff = new Date("June 07, 2013 20:13:00");
var now = new Date();
var timeDiff = kickoff.getTime() - now.getTime();
if (timeDiff <= 0) {
       clearTimeout ("timer");

       }




var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours %=24;
minutes %=60;
seconds %= 60;
if (seconds < 10) {
 seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
if (minutes < 10) {
 minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (hours < 10) {
 hours = "0" + hours;
}
if (days < 10) {
 days = "0" + days;
}


document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("secondsBox").innerHTML = seconds;

var timer = setTimeout('cdtd()',1000);
}
```

Comment: You're passing strings to the timeout functions instead of the actual references needed. Should look something like `clearTimeout(timer);` and `setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);` Note that you don't include the `()` to pass the function. `cdtd()` will actually execute the function right then and try to pass the return value (undefined) to setTimeout.

Comment: Well the timer works, when I put something like:
    
    document.write("Time up");
under the clearTimeout it replaces the whole thing with the writing bu I just want to replace the div in which the timer is enclosed in with another div sourced from the html page, if that is possible. Thanks will revise the code.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, `setInterval()` function would work out better. Just remove the `setTimeout()` and *outside* of your function, add:

```
setInterval(cdtd, 1000);
```

Hope this helps. You can read more about `setInterval()` here: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: Ok will try it, I actually thought that it could be done by simply putting some code under the setTimeout, how would You go about replacing a div with another div ?

Comment: If you have a parent div with ID "div-id", you can do, `document.getElementById("div-id").innerHTML=''`, this will clear out anything inside the div, then do, `document.getElementById("div-id").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete solution bellow with the HTML part.

The function needed to be called once.

The clearTimeout take an timer object as an argument and not a String I've thought that putting the setTimer inside the condition would just do better.

Output is not so great when `timeDiff <= 0` but this is not really part of the question.

Happy coding!

```
<html>
<body>
    <span id="daysBox"></span>
    <span id="hoursBox"></span>
    <span id="minsBox"></span>
    <span id="secondsBox"></span>

<script>
var timer = null;
function cdtd() {
    var kickoff = new Date("June 08, 2013 20:13:00");
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = kickoff.getTime() - now.getTime();


    if (timeDiff > 0) {
        setTimeout('cdtd()', 1000);
    }

    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %=24;
    minutes %=60;
    seconds %= 60;
    if (seconds < 10) {
     seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
     minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (hours < 10) {
     hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (days < 10) {
     days = "0" + days;
    }


    document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById("secondsBox").innerHTML = seconds;

    }
    cdtd();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of teaching and learning.  There are a few things to keep in mind in JavaScript.

1. The DOM is slow as hell.
2. The DOM is pretty slow.
3. Do as few DOM operations as possible.

Okay well not really, but keep in mind that doing calls like documentGetElementById has to talk to the DOM, which can be fairly expensive.

HTML

```
<div id="timerContent"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
// No point to recalculate these every timer evaluation.
var kickoff = new Date("June 07, 2013 20:13:00"),
    timerContainer = document.getElementById('timerContent'),
    timer; // Added for visibility in the global scope.


function cdtd() {
  var now = new Date(),
      timeDiff = kickoff.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (timeDiff <= 0) {

     clearTimeout(timer);
     timerContainer.innerHTML = '<div>KICK OFF!!!!</div> <img src="xxxxx" />';

  } else {

    // This style of declaration is just preference.
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000),
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
        hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60),
        days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    if (days < 10) days = "0" + days;

    // Using an array simplifies the process of creating the text
    // In some browsers this is more performant than using '' + ''
    // In other browsers it's not, in reality the difference marginal in
    // small iterations like this one.
    var textTemplateArray = [
          days, 'Days',
          minutes, 'Minutes',
          hours, 'Hours',
          seconds, 'Seconds'
        ];

    timerContainer.innerHTML = textTemplateArray.join(' ');
  }
}

timer = setInterval(cdtd, 1000);
```